# The usage of "you" vs. "yourself" in an imperative sentence

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence "Learn how to protect you and your property . . ." I believe that "you" should be changed to "yourself," since the understood imperative subject of the sentence is "you."

Your thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it's reflexive, so 'yourself' is the right word.

Comment: But there is no possessive reflexive pronoun, so _yourself and your property_ is not as parallel as _you and your property_. If you want that conjoined phrase to stay parallel, ignore the reflexive and use _you_.

Comment: Yes, but would you not then be saying, in effect "(You must) learn how to protect you"? What would we do if "your property" were not part of the mix?

Comment: ... Do you still say things like "James can drive faster than I"? Very few Anglophones would. But the usual "James can drive faster than me" corresponds 'in effect' to "James can drive faster than me can". English doesn't always stick to logical forms. // That said, I'd use 'yourself' here, sacrificing strict parallelism.